# Calculating the exponential of an upper triangular matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

> Find the matrix exponential $e^A$ for
> $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 1 & 1\\
> 0 & 2 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 2\\
> \end{bmatrix}.$$

I think we should use the proberty

> If $AB = BA$ then $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$.

We can use that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
+\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Both matrices obviously commute. But I dont know how to calculate the exponential of

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Could you help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should decompose your matrix like this
$$\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 2 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 2 
 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 2 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
The left one commutes with the right one and the right one is nilpotent. So it is easy to compute.

Comment: It might be useful to note that this is always possible (in $\mathbb{C}$) thanks to the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition : wiki/Jordan–Chevalley_decomposition

Comment: @GabrieleCassese Good point! I recently find that mastering the calculating of matrices adeptly is important for studying Lie theory and representation theory. In fact, J-C decomposition is significant in Lie algebra theory.

Answer (score 5):

We may use Cayley Hamilton theorem to find the exponential of $$ M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Note that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $1,1,1$

We write $$e^{tM} = \alpha (t)I+ \beta (t)M+ \gamma (t) M^2.$$

To find the  coefficient functions we replace $M$ with $\lambda$ and solve the resulting system.

$$e^{t\lambda} = \alpha (t)I+ \beta (t)\lambda + \gamma (t) \lambda ^2.$$

Differentiating with respect to $\lambda $ we get $$te^{\lambda t}=\beta + 2\lambda \gamma$$
Differentiating again, we get $$t^2 e^{\lambda t }=2\gamma$$

With t=1 and $\lambda =1$ we get $$\alpha = e/2, \beta =0, \gamma = e/2$$

with these values we find $$e^M =e \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3/2\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Apply the same method with $\lambda =2$ we get $$e^N =e^2 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3/2\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}. $$

for the original matrix $$N=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: As pointed out by @XTChen there is a much easier way to do this but I detail evaluation of the requested exponential nonetheless.

Note that
$$\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1}^n=\pmatrix{1&n&n(n+1)/2\\0&1&n\\0&0&1}$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty & \frac1{n!}\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1}^n  \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\pmatrix{1&n&n(n+1)/2\\0&1&n\\0&0&1}\\
&=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\pmatrix{1/n!&1/(n-1)!&(n+1)/(2(n-1)!)\\0&1/n!&1/(n-1)!\\0&0&1/n!}\\
&=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}+\pmatrix{e-1&e&3e/2\\0&e-1&e\\0&0&e-1}\\
&=\pmatrix{e&e&3e/2\\0&e&e\\0&0&e}\\
&=\frac12e\pmatrix{2&2&3\\0&2&2\\0&0&2}\\
\end{align}